# MySQL-Query: GROUP_CONCAT() doesn't work correctly

Tags: mysql, product-list, category-attribute

I try to execute this SQL-query, but I don't get the right result:

```
SELECT k.product_id,  product.sku, group_concat(i.value) 
FROM catalog_product_super_link AS par  
LEFT JOIN  staging.catalog_category_product k ON k.product_id = par.parent_id 
LEFT JOIN  catalog_product_entity AS product ON k.product_id = product.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN  catalog_category_entity_varchar AS p ON p.entity_id = k.category_id LEFT JOIN  catalog_category_entity_varchar i  ON i.entity_id = k.category_id 
WHERE  product.entity_id = 368538 
GROUP BY par.parent_id, k.category_id
```

Can someone help?

Comment: what is the result, and why is it wrong, and which result do you expect?

Comment: i get the categories in different rows, and i want to get them in one row, i tried with group_concat() but i didn t get the right result

Comment: you try to group_concat the column "value" from table "i", but I don't see a table "i" in your query. I think you might mean p.value, as "p" is the only table in your query that should have a column named "value"

Answer (score 0):

Check the part where it says

`catalog_category_entity_varchar i`

It should be

`catalog_category_entity_varchar AS i`

Also this one:

`staging.catalog_category_product k`

Should be

`catalog_category_product AS k`

Unless you're using some kind of shorthand code that I don't know of.

Comment: "The AS keyword is optional when aliasing a select_expr with an identifier." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: That's what I suspected. But still the `staging.catalog_category_product k` line is not correct I think.

Comment: I think he is using a different database for some of the tables

Comment: found it :) "You can refer to a table within the default database as tbl_name, or as db_name.tbl_name to specify a database explicitly" same link as above :)

Comment: Ok, but it can still be the cause of the issue :) Anyway, the best way to debug it is to split the query by removing parts, going through it step by step and see the resulting data.

Comment: agreed... i don't even understand the question, what's the "right result"? :D

Comment: But nice find by the way, I didn't know that regarding referencing separate databases.

Comment: Haha I know. The actual SQL data would be nice.